# Slimpay Illegal state Error when try to call orders.get_mandates method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When i try to call get_mandates method of Slimpay using 'https://github.com/novagile/slimpay' Gem it is giving me 903 Ambiguous handler methods mapped Error(http://prntscr.com/dz8goe).

```
orders = Slimpay::Order.new()
mendatedet = orders.get_orders({
    creditorReference: Slimpay.configuration.creditor_reference, 
    reference: @orderReference
})

@mendatedetails = JSON.parse(mendatedet)

if(@mendatedetails['state'] == 'closed.completed')  
    @manHref = @mendatedetails['_links']['https://api.slimpay.net/alps#get-mandate']['href'].split('/') 
    #@manHref[4] is Customer ID which is working in Browser
    @gtMen = orders.get_mandates({
        "creditorReference": Slimpay.configuration.creditor_reference,
        "id": @manHref[4],
        "paymentScheme": @mendatedetails['paymentScheme']
    })
    render json: @gtMen 
end
```

Comment: Can you post some code related to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the mandate related to the order?

If so, you already have the link right there:
`@mendatedetails['_links']['https://api.slimpay.net/alps#get-mandate']['href']`

Send a GET request to this and you will get the mandate you are looking for.

And if I understand the code correctly, you can use this as a shortcut:

```
@gtMen = mendatedet.get_mandate()
render json: @gtMen
```

You may also consider renaming mendatedet to orderdet because what you have in it is the order.

Comment: I have tried your answer. But still not resolved and same error.

Comment: My problem solved using GET Request Mandate URL with some change in structure of URL.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is due to the wrong URL call.In sign mandate Response, I got 'https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/mandates/userid' which when i try to directly call gives Error. Instead of directle call it, I use HTTP request with updated URL 'https://api-sandbox.slimpay.net/mandates/?id=userid'. and it give me all response. Slimpay API gem try to call Mandate Directly that cause error.

**Here is my code**

```
@href = @OrderDet['_links']['https://api.slimpay.net/alps#get-mandate']['href'].to_s
@manHref = @href.split('/')
@customID = @manHref[4]

appOpt =    {
       'Accept' => "application/hal+json; profile='https://api.slimpay.net/alps/v1'",
       'Content-type' => 'application/hal+json',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'scope' => 'api'
}
@basic_auth = { username: "#{Slimpay.configuration.client_id}", password: Slimpay.configuration.client_secret }
getTok = HTTParty.post('https://api.slimpay.net/oauth/token', basic_auth: @basic_auth, body: appOpt)
@token = getTok['access_token']
myArray = @manHref
myArray.pop
@urlTest = myArray.join("/")
appOpt1 = {
    'Accept' => "application/hal+json",
    'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@token}"
}
@reqUR = "#{@urlTest}?id=#{@customID}"
getMen = HTTParty.get(@reqUR, headers: appOpt1)
@mendatedetails = JSON.parse(getMen)

@logData.mandateres = getMen
```